# alert not firing in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and the first alert gives me an X but then the if block never fires. I'm sure its something simple I'm doing wrong...

```
$('.collectionofdates1>.datenumber').click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
    if($(this).html() == "X"){
    alert('asdf');
    return false;
    }
else{
    $('.collectionofdates1 .datenumber').removeClass('selecteddate');
$(this).addClass('selecteddate');
}
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML. Could be an incorrect selector, but we can't tell without seeing the HTML.

Comment: Is there a space on either side of the 'X'?

Comment: try changing first alert to 
alert("______"+$(this).html()+"_________");

Comment: it was a space on each side of the X. thanks!

Comment: Why would `$(this).html()` ever equal `"X"`? Wouldn't the better money be on `if ($(this).text() == "X")`? Also, jQuery has a method that will remove th extra white space. See [jQuery.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/). **example:** `var txt = $(this).text().trim();`

Answer (score 0):

2 recommendations:

1) put spaces in your selectors: `$('.collectionofdates1 > .datenumber')`

2) use text() when you mean text(), not html().  Also use .trim() to make sure you don't have whitespace: `if($(this).text().trim() == 'X'){`